# ListBox MenuItem Data template binding

Tags: c#, binding, menu

I have he following code:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>



        <ListBox.ContextMenu >
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemDataList}">

                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:MenuItemData}" >
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.ContextMenu>

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

It throws this exception message when i right click in order to show the pop-up menu:

```
Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.
```

`ItemsList` and `MenuItemDataList` are diferent collections.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the datatemplate inside the ContextMenu.ItemTemplate

```
       <ListBox.ContextMenu >
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemDataList}">
                <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:MenuItemData}">
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>

            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.ContextMenu>
```